# SQL running total from previous year

Tags: mysql, sql

How to do running total or cumulative sum from this query? Is it possible to run by correlated subquery? The cumulative sum results will be show as 'New value'.

```
SELECT
  sum(data2.quantity/1000) AS UnitMT
FROM
  data2
INNER JOIN itmnocate ON data2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
                    and Source in ('imported','local','by product')
WHERE date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12', '%Y-01-01')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
 AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12', '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 AND data2.unit = 'KG'
 and data2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')
GROUP BY month(date1)
```

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query, and is a correlated subquery a requirement?

Comment: At the moment yes. Because I need to run the query in Jaspersoft iReport and it doesnt run the query with variable like set @sum :=0; for some reason.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: so jaspersoft can't execute this query: `select x.*,@i:=@i+1 i from data2 x,(select @i:=0) vars order by date1;` ??

Comment: @Strawberry yes. I have tried and it wont execute somehow.

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: Well, if you provide an MCVE, I'm sure someone will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cumulative problem If your mysql version support [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) you can use `SUM` with window function to do cumulative.

The `DATE1` column can be used as the basis for `order by` to do cumulative.

```
SELECT *,
       sum(UnitMT) over (order by month(date1)) 'New value'
FROM T t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocPZYQ6MVsg3kFfkTRgpDT/0)

---

If your mysql version didn't support *window function*, you can try to use subquery in `select` to do cumulative.

```
CREATE TABLE T( date1 DATE,UnitMT int);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-01-01',66535);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-02-01',108337);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-03-01',132767);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-04-01',100687);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-05-01',125151);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,
      (SELECT SUM(UnitMT) FROM T tt WHERE month(tt.date1) <= month(t1.date1)) 'New value'
FROM T t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33837/2/0)**:

```
|      date1 | UnitMT | New value |
|------------|--------|-----------|
| 2017-01-01 |  66535 |     66535 |
| 2017-02-01 | 108337 |    174872 |
| 2017-03-01 | 132767 |    307639 |
| 2017-04-01 | 100687 |    408326 |
| 2017-05-01 | 125151 |    533477 |
```

**Note**

`T` symbol your current result set data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query, it's efficient and works an all MySQL versions:

```
select @cumSum := 0;

select UnitMT, @cumSum := @cumSum + UnitMT
from tbl
order by date1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDgpMoUzyRKV8Q4kYmW3aN/1)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, you can use variables and a subquery:

```
SELECT mon, UnitMT,
       (@sum := @sum + UnitMT) as running_sum
FROM (SELECT month(date1) as mon, sum(data2.quantity/1000) AS UnitMT
      FROM data2 INNER JOIN
           itmnocate
           ON data2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber AND
              Source IN ('imported', 'local', 'by product')
      WHERE date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12', '%Y-01-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND
            date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12', '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND
           data2.unit = 'KG' AND
           data2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')
      GROUP BY month(date1)
      ORDER BY month(date1)
     ) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @sum := 0) params;
```

Comment: Before this i cant use variables query on jaspersoft ireport, but this works fine somehow. Thanks!